# In Cloud foundry why doesn't .profile work when added using sbt but does when injected into Jar?

Tags: sbt, cloud-foundry

I have read the documentation for the Cloud Foundry Java Buildpack and found that using a `.profile` file is not supported:
https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html#profile

> Note: The Java buildpack does not support pre-runtime hooks.

However, if I add the `.profile` file to the Fat Zip that is generated using sbt:

`/usr/local/bin/sbt "project address-index-server"  universal:packageBin
jar uf server/target/universal/address-index-server.zip .profile`

The `.profile` is executed when uploaded to Cloud Foundry.  My hope was to place the `.profile` file into the main git repository of the application and use `build.sbt` to copy the file into the Fat Zip.  Though the file is present in the archive it is not executed when uploading to Cloud Foundry.

I've had another pair of eyes to see that there is no difference in the two files.  I can only assume something is happening when using the `jar` command, but I don't understand what.

For reference the sbt line is:

`mappings in Universal += file(s"$serverDir/.profile") -> ".profile",`

I have verified that the `.profile` file is located in the same location in both Fat Zips that are created using either the `sbt` method or `jar` update.

So why doesn't the `sbt` method work?

update: I have found that the `jar` inject method works with cf version `6.22.1+6b7af9c-2016-09-24` (Pivotal Online) but not `6.21.0+dff2cf8-2016-07-27`, the version we have internally.

Comment: When you push and the script is not executed, can you `cf ssh` into the container?  If so, look to see that `.profile` exists and is where you'd expect it to be.  Also, maybe compare that to a `cf push` that succeeds.  Just a guess, but maybe there's a permissions issue on the file?  Also, sounds like it's possibly a cli issue, maybe check the release notes for the cli and see if there are any changes that might result in the behavior difference you're seeing.

Comment: @DanielMikusa I can't ssh into the container as it fails to load: `Error opening SSH connection: Application "address-index-api-shim" is not in the STARTED state`.  This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303539/how-do-i-bundle-a-custom-c-shared-library-with-java-application-in-cloud-foundry

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error.  I would first suggest confirming that you can SSH to an app.  Your CF provider would need to enable and support this.  It requires them to be running a Diego backend and to have allowed users to do this.  See here for more details.  https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html